# Finding indices of numbers closest to zero (list)

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, indices

I have a list of numbers, when i plot them I get this top-hat type function. The FWHM occurs at zero on the y axis. Therefore, if i find out the x values where the plot hits zero (in two places), the difference will give me the FWHM.

However, each number in the list is a float so I have to find the numbers closest to zero. CAX_roots is the list which is plotted. I can find the first using the following code:

```
root =  min(abs(x) for x in CAX_roots)
first_root = str(CAX_roots).find(str(root))
print first_root
```

Any help/advice on how I would find the second root? I can't seem to get past the error "list indices must be integers, not tuple" when i try continuing the iteration from the first_root value to the end of the list:

```
CAX_roots2 = CAX_roots[first_root,:]
root2 =  min(abs(x) for x in CAX_roots2)
```

Or if a better way to do this? thanks in advance!

[image: Plotting CAX_roots, where i am interested in finding the values where the plot goes through zero]

Comment: you have an errant comma here  `CAX_roots[first_root,:]`

Comment: Yep, I started to comment,  but figured it was worth an answer as a 'trap for young players'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code

```
CAX_roots2 = CAX_roots[first_root,:]
root2 =  min(abs(x) for x in CAX_roots2)
```

Is exactly as it appears in your program, the problem is coming from the comma in `[first_root,:]`. You need to specify it as `[first_root:]`.

The trailing comma is how you specify a tuple with a single element.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1,
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> type (b)
<type 'tuple'>
>>>
```

But, as @Reticality points out first_root is a float which is not what you want as an index.

Instead, if you think about what you are trying to find - it's the interva for an inequality `(f(x) >=0)`. So use that:

```
signs = [x >= 0 for x in CAX_roots]
first_root_index = signs.index(True)
second_root_index = signs[first_root_index:].index(False) + first_root_index - 1
first_root = CAX_roots[first_root_index]
second_root = CAX_roots[second_root_index]
```

As you can see here

```
>>> l = [-2, -1, 0, 2, 3, 0, -1]
>>> v = [x >=0 for x in l]
>>> v
[False, False, True, True, True, True, False]
>>> v.index(True)
2
>>> v[2:].index(False)
4
>>> l[2]
0
>>> l[2+4-1]
0
>>>
```

To be robust, you'll need to deal with `ValueError` exceptions from the `index()` calls should your data never become positive or return to negative.

Comment: Thank you for the correction and explanation, it was quite thorough! I see what you mean about the comma now and using a float as an index. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Close. You have a tuple as an index because of a trailing comma. You probably don't want `first_root` as the index, as it is a float. If you want to remove the value from the list, do this:

```
CAX_roots2 = CAX_roots[:]  # So they don't reference the same object
CAX_roots2.pop(CAX_roots2.index(first_root))  # Pop the first root's index
```